# WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse: How to

Tags: websphere

I installed WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse over the top of Spring Tool Suite. I used the Help > Eclipse Marketplace menu to do it.

The install seems to have worked okay (no failures). But I don't don't know where the WebSphere runtime environment(s) has been installed. I would have expected it to be in c:\Program Files\IBM\Websphere but it isn't there.

When I go to the Spring tool suite directories....

C:\Program Files\springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\features

There are a lot of new WebSphere directories, hence I know it has installed something. Just not sure where.

It's got me thinking whether or not the developer tools provides a standard run time environment with stopServer.bat, startServer.bat etc.

Your help to assist me understanding how the tools work would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no, the tools suite wont install a server runtime environment. So you have a couple of options to have WebSphere up and running in your environment.

WebSphere Liberty profile - This you can install from Eclipse Market Place, just do a search for WebSphere Liberty and install it, you should be good to go. You should notice that Liberty is a complete new product and is not the same as WebSphere N.D that is more commonly used by large companies.
You can learn more about liberty profile at: 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/cwlp_about.html

or

WebSphere Developer Edidtion - You can download and install from: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/ 
This one is just like WebSphere N.D but it is free for development and targeted to developers to run locally while developing their applications.

You can check WebSphere versions comparsion at: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/wasfamily/compare.html

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. That helps me a lot. So when I installed the developer tools what did that install?

Comment: IBM® WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse has tools for:
Managing the server, such as starting and stopping.
Starting a remote server.
Publishing local and server-side code.
Controlling incremental publishing.
When combined with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse provides a lightweight environment for developing Java EE applications.
WebSphere related wizards(like generating HTTPRouter for WebServices enabled EJBs and WebService clients)....
So.. mostly developer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It is a great idea to use WebSphere Liberty Profile as a local server runtime instead. It is extremely lightweight and it understands the same deployment descriptor syntax from WebSphere "full" profile.

The Liberty runtime can be downloaded and installed directly from Eclipse after the WDT installation you performed.